# Who is the Rishi Hiranyastupa of the family of Angiras?

Tags: scripture, rishi, shatapatha-brahmana

**[Shatapatha Brahmana 1.6.4](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1229.htm)** mentions that Indra after hurling the thunderbolt at Vritra, hid himself and certain divinities were deputed to find him:

> 2. **Agni of the deities, Hiranyastûpa of the Rishis, and the Brihatî of the metres,** set about searching for him. Agni discovered him and stayed with him (as a guest) that (day and) night. He (Indra), namely, is the Vasu of the gods, for he is their hero.

The footnote mentions a little more detail about Hiranyastupa:

> 175:2 Hiranyastûpa, of the family of the Aṅgiras, is the reputed author (or seer) of the hymns Rig-veda I, 31-35; IX, 4; 69. Of these, I, 32 and 33, which celebrate the exploits of Indra, seem to have been especially prized.

**I want to know if any scriptures give more details about the origins and life story of rishi Hiranyastupa besides what is already mentioned above.**

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but I found this - Brahmin was initiated with Gaayatri of Vishwamitra, Kshaktriya with Trishtub attributed to Hiranyastupa, Vaishya with Jagatti of Vamadeva - https://sites.google.com/site/kanyakubjbrahminsgroup/home/gotra-of-kanyakubj-brahmins

Comment: Thanks @AmritDhara it does show he was a rishi of importance!